# Width of vertical rulers automatically changing in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am not quite sure how to describe my problem, therefore I have attached two printscreens with my question.

I am using Sublime Text 3 and in some files of my C program the width of the vertical rulerz seems automatically to be shrinking (in the first picture it is shrinked, in the second is another file and there it is not).

In some of them it looks really squeezed. So i am wondering if someone knows which preference setting i am searching for so i can turn it of?

[image: how I dont want it to be]

[image: how I want it to be]

Comment: View menu -> Indentation -> Tab Width

Comment: thank you keith. But do you know how can i turn it off?

Comment: Oh i think I found it, auto indent i guess it is! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These vertical rulers are called Indentation Guides in Sublime Text speak. Where they appear is based on your indentation settings. ST tries to automatically detect the "tab width"/"tab size" based on the contents of the file, so this is why it might differ.

If ST gets it wrong, you can choose the appropriate width in the View menu -> Indentation -> Tab Width.

Comment: yes I can choose it there, thank you for pointing me to the right direction!